# How to increase audio file volume

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

How to increase audio file volume? My app records calls, and its volume is low. Is there a way to increase the recorded call volume? Here is my code:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(2);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Comment: I've added the android tag - remove it if it's incorrect.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317772/increase-volume-of-recording-android-audiorecord) is a duplicate. I'll refrain from flagging the question as such since there is no accepted answer and I can't vouch for the quality of the only answer.

Comment: Are you using java sound API? i would have an answer for you if you do

Comment: Ulug Toprak , no i am not using sound api !!!

Answer (score 0):

While using `MediaPlayer` you can call the `setVolume(float,float)` method with your object.

For eg-

`MediaPlayer media = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.your_file);
media.setVolume(0,0);`

The value passed as parameters are on a logarithmic scale from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use Something like this**

```
  player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.got);

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                player.start();
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setLooping(false);
                player.setVolume(100, 100);
                playAudioWithDelaysound();
                stopSelf();
            }
        });

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }
```

> use as you needed