# Change Android Microphone Sensitivity For Speech Recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have an Android device (TV-Box, running Android 4.2)  with an attached USB Microphone. I'm developing an Application which uses VoiceRecognition for that Android device and I want to change the microphone sensitivity.

How can I achieve this? In the Android settings under "Sound Input Devices", I can only change

- "mic input"
- "LineIn input"
- "usbaudio input"

but there is no way to set the sensitivity of the microphone. 
Is there an app that I can use? (Though I couldn't find any) Or can I do this somehow in the java code?

**My voice-recognition class: (simplified)**

```
public class VoiceCommandService extends Service {

    protected SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                this.getPackageName());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,4);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with an USB microphone... On my phone I have a settings in Audio > Devices > Microphone sensitivity but it may be device dependent. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441166/how-to-adjust-microphone-sensitivity-while-recording-audio-in-android-solved

Comment: Have you found an answer?