# Play sound to a headset and record from the speakerphone microphone

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

In android, you can play and record sound in the speaker mode: [`setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean on)`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn(boolean)).

In this case, the system will use the loudspeaker and a special 'loud' record configuration for the mic (I am not sure how it is called properly).

The speakerphone mode is not compatible with any headphones/headsets, so I do not use it with them. It is OK with headsets. But with headphones (without a mic), I have to speak directly to the phone's microphone, because the sound record level is much lower than in the speakerphone mode.

My questions is whether there is a way to output sound to headphones and record using the above mentioned 'loud' record configuration?

Comment: _"a special 'loud' configuration for the microphone (I am not sure how it is called properly)."_ I believe you're talking about the _farfield_ microphone configuration. Have you tried using `AudioSource.CAMCORDER`?

Comment: Have you checked this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441166/how-to-adjust-microphone-sensitivity-while-recording-audio-in-android-solved

Comment: @Michael, no, that's not it. When I call `setSpeakerphoneOn` the input microphone does not get changed (I have farfield mic on the top and nearfield mic on the bottom of the device, so it is easy to figure out which one is used at the moment). Nevetheless, the sound record volume is much louder when `setSpeakerphoneOn` is set.