# Low volume in call recording (Rx)

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I do the following test:

Call from android app phone to home phone, first speak from (android phone - > home phone), in the same call speak from (home phone-> android phone).

The voice (android phone - > home phone) sounds in good volume (10/10 volume). But the voice (home phone-> android phone) sounds very low (4/10 volume).

I do the same test with random [call recording app in play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=il.co.smedia.callrecorder.yoni&hl=es) The voice (android phone - > home phone) sounds in good volume (10/10 volume). The voice (home phone-> android phone) sounds in good volume (10/10 volume)

I try to call record which:

1)

> audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

2)

> audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)

3)

> audioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL)

With 1, 2 o 3 results are very similar.

I also try to up VOICE_CALL stream if AudioSource.VOICE_CALL is used like this:

```
audioManager manager = (AudioManager) ServiceClass
                    .getServiceContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                    manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL),
                    AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Does the application I have tried in the Play Store process the audio in some way to turn up the volume?

I don´t show here audio quality set code because in both test (my app test, play store app test) the audio (android phone - > home phone) sounds exactly the same, the problem is (home phone-> android phone)

Answer (score 0):

I would try adjusting mic sensitivity in your code.
Heres a link to another stackoverflow quesiton being answered to do this.

[How to adjust microphone sensitivity while recording audio in android - Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441166/how-to-adjust-microphone-sensitivity-while-recording-audio-in-android-solved)

Comment: Then you use AudioRecord instead of MediaRecorder in call record to up volume?