# how to increase Voice call microphone volume to maximum

Tags: java, android

I have tried everything to increase the microphone volume of the voice call in android studio but I still can't do it. I managed to do something close in engineer mode but I want to implement something like it in my app. I have tried using AudioManager which I saw no difference when I tried.

```
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    am.setStreamVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
            0);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase Microphone volume level in Android PJSIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861391/how-to-increase-microphone-volume-level-in-android-pjsip)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried exactly. You might find it helpful to read: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AliakseiStadnik I updated it.