# How to change microphone sensitivity in android java

Tags: java, android, microphone

I did a record voice app that works with a `bluetooth` headset.
Its very simple and its working fine.

But the sound recorded are to loud.

id like change the sensitivity from my `microphone` captation.

how can i do it ? i dont know the method that control its

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer here:

[How to adjust microphone sensitivity while recording audio in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441166/how-to-adjust-microphone-sensitivity-while-recording-audio-in-android)

As noted you can't do this on the fly but could give the user control over the input volume, rather than hardcoding it yourself.

Comment: how can i give the user control of input volume?

Comment: You could add a slider element to the ui, then set float gain to that as in the example

Comment: and tehre is a way to make this example in a active call?